# how to Render CSS with Razor instead of HTML

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a CSS using this code

```
input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

and the HTML page has the following code to use the CSS

```
<input id="product-name" type="text" required="required">
```

I want to use the Razor in the view to render the text box called product-name 
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `TextBox` helper:

```
@Html.TextBox("product-name", null, new { required = "required" })
```

But personally I would recommend you to use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

and then have the controller action populate and pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.ProductName = "some product name";
    return View(model);
}
```

and now your view could be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProductName, new { required = "required" })
```

Comment: And how can i control the text from .cs class ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the proper way to do this using a view model. As an alternative you could set the value in ViewData from the controller action: `ViewData["product-name"] = "some product name";`. But personally that's not the approach I would recommend you. Strongly typed views and view models is the correct way to do ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Using textBoxFor doesn't feel the CSS style, I should use class from css called text but It can't feel it even when I changed new{@class="text"}
any idea about what to do /

Comment: well, It did works but one more thing while validating it with jQuery, it always return true even the box has no value.
have you ever faced this problem before ?

Comment: Get rid of the `required="required"` attribute and decorate your view model property with the `[Required]` validation attribute. Now all you need to do is include the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` and you will get automatic client side validation out of the box without the need to write any custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the helper and add a class attribute to it to connect it to the css..

```
@Html.TextBox("name", null, new { id = "product-name", @class = "textbox", required = "required" });
```

and the css will change to

```
.textbox {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

Comment: And how can I control the input text from that text box in the .cs file ?